# Javascript/PHP Library for finding air density?

Tags: php, javascript, weather

Are there any good libraries for finding air density for Javascript/PHP? I'm not a total chemistry wiz!

Comment: what are your inputs?  Depending on that, it's likely just simple math...

Comment: Density = mass/volume, or are you looking for unit conversion type stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the density of air doesn't require a library, it's just a single equation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air

For dry air you use: `density = pressure / (specificgasconstant * temperature)`

For humid air you use: `density = (drypressure / (specificdrygasconstant * temperature)) + (vaporpressure / (specificvaporgasconstant * temperature))`

That page has all the various equations you'd need to find the variable inputs (difference between the dry air pressure and the water vapor pressure in humid air) and the constants you'd need as well, and tells how to determine air density by altitude and all that.

Comment: Thanks Phoenix! Just outta random curiosity, do you know how altitude and pressure correlate?

Comment: It's down near the bottom on that page, big equation to find air pressure at a specific altitude, and then to determine probable density from that.

Comment: This page has a bunch of the same equations and also goes into dew points and all that as well as more on altitude/pressure/density calculations: http://wahiduddin.net/calc/density_altitude.htm

Comment: By the way, since all air has some humidity, except maybe in the driest of places, the second equation is probably more accurate for most applications, while the first equation is more for the ideal conditions of absolutely dry air, such as you might find in laboratory conditions.  Besides, if there is no water vapor, then the second part of the humid air equation will come out to `0/(constant * temperature)`, which is just `0`, leaving just the first part of the equation, which is the same as the dry air equation.